# How to decode and download base64 string(excel data) and download the file?

Tags: javascript, excel, vue.js, base64

I'm getting excel data encoded as base64 string from backend. I want to decode this data and download the excel file in the browser. I'm using vuejs as my frontend. Also if I were to show this data in table format on the frontend, how can I go about doing that? Thanks in advance for the response.

This is what I have tried-

```
public downloadfile() {
    var data = window.atob("string");
    this.save("file", data, ".xls");
  }
  public save(name: any, data: any, type: any) {
    var bytes = new Array(data.length);
    console.log("here", bytes);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      bytes[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    data = new Uint8Array(bytes);
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type });
    console.log(blob);
    let objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let anchor = document.createElement("a");

    anchor.href = objectURL;
    anchor.download = name;
    anchor.click();

    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
  }
```

I have a run button on clicking that downloadfile runs. and a file.txt gets downloaded. What am I doing wrong here? If I rename the file format to xls, that file shows correct data.

Answer (score 0):

You need a browser Javascript library that understands excel format. I have used sheetjs with good success in the past.

Comment: Is therer a way to show it in html table tags? I guess I would need the data in json from backend if I'm not wrong.

Comment: No need to have the back end do anything besides serving the file. The entire parsing is done in the browser and the result can be interated by row and colum. They have an example on their site which demos your exact usage. Ajax a file and display the spreadsheet in html table tags.